# Getting a larger linearly independent set by adding one or more vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

In my homework I came across this question and have no idea about how to prove that?

we have a set of 4 linearly independent vectors in R4. Is it possible to get a larger linearly independent set by adding one or more vectors to this set?

edit: sorry for miswriting. they are in R4

Comment: If you are in $R^n$ where $n>4$ yes. Otherwise no.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, if the vectors are in a space of dimension greater than $4$. In this case, we would have that the four linearly independent vectors fail to span the vector space in which they exist.

No otherwise.

Every finite subset of a set of linearly independent vectors is linearly independent. So your vectors may be a subset of a larger set of linearly independent vectors, if the space in which they are embedded has dimension greater than four.

Comment: is it also tru for dependent vectors?
is Every finite subset of a set of linearly dependent vectors linearly dependent?

Comment: No, not necessarily. It is not necessarily true when dealing when dealing with a linearly dependent vectors. Feel free to accept the answer, if it was helpful! $\large \checkmark$.